# Cite two papers in parentheses with page numbers

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

I'd like to cite two papers in one parenthesis, like

[cite1; p.100, cite2; p.200]

How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
    
    \cite[p.100, p.200]{Bredon, Chaber}
    
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
        \bibitem{Bredon} Bredon, G. E.
        
        \bibitem{Chaber} Chaber, J. 
    
    \end{thebibliography}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to provide information about that setup you are using. Bibtex, biblatex, plain bibliography.

Comment: And of course you're used `style` in Biblatex or similar. Mist of them offer different options for citing. Maybe `\parencites{keyq}{key2}`, Or you just give `(\cite[123]{citekey}, \cite[123]{citekey})` a try. But as you see, without further informatios its just guessing...

Comment: Please also state whether you want to generate numeric-style or authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Comment: @Mico Like this [Bredon; p.100, Chaber; p.200]

Comment: Please post a **new query** rather than post a hard-to-find-follow-up.

Answer (score 3):

> Like this `[Bredon; p.100, Chaber; p.200]`

I take it that you've constructed the bibliography by hand, i.e., by setting up various `\bibitem` directives. I further take it that you want to show *author-only* citation call-outs rather than the more common author-year style citation call-outs.

If these assumptions are correct, the following solution may be of interest to you. It employs the `natbib` citation management package and its `\citeauthor` and `\citetext` macros. Note that it's important to provide both an optional argument (in square brackets -- note that it's essential to provide both author- and year-related information) and a mandatory argument (the "key", in curly braces) for each `\bibitem`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib} % for '\citetext' and '\citeauthor' macros
\setcitestyle{square,notesep={; }}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % just to avoid an outright error message

\begin{document}

\noindent
\dots\ \citetext{\citeauthor[p.~100]{Bredon}, \citeauthor[p.~200]{Chaber}} \dots

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Bredon(1995)]{Bredon} Bredon, G. E., 1995, \dots

\bibitem[Chaber(2005)]{Chaber} Chaber, J. 2005, \dots

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment (comments, actually): To generate numeric style citation call-outs of the form `[1; p.100, 2; p.200]`, I suggest you (a) change

```
\setcitestyle{square,notesep={; }}
```

to

```
\setcitestyle{numbers,square,notesep={; }}
```

and (b) replace

```
\citetext{\citeauthor[p.~100]{Bredon}, \citeauthor[p.~200]{Chaber}}
```

with

```
\citetext{\citealp[p.~100]{Bredon}, \citealp[p.~200]{Chaber}}
```

Then, recompile the test document twice to get this output:

[image]

Comment: How to produce like [1; p.100, 2; p.200]?

Comment: @MehmetOnat - To generate this form of numeric-style citation call-out s, I suggest you (a) change `\setcitestyle{square,notesep={; }}` to `\setcitestyle{numbers,square,notesep={; }}`, i.e., add the option `numbers`, and (b) change `\citetext{\citeauthor[p.~100]{Bredon}, \citeauthor[p.~200]{Chaber}}` to `\citetext{\citealp[p.~100]{Bredon}, \citealp[p.~200]{Chaber}}`, i.e., replace both instances of `\citeauthor` with `\citealp`.

Comment: I think it doesnt work. It adds only year.

Comment: @MehmetOnat - It *does* work. Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: it's interesting it didn't work then it works now. Thank you so much